# access Oauth Token via bash/batch file

Tags: r, bash, terminal, rstudio, gmail-api

I am trying to access Gmail via R script to save attachments with gmailr library. R script for the task is as follows:

---

```
require(gmailr)

search_sub <- toString(Sys.Date())

tbl2<- unlist(messages(search = (search_sub), num_results = NULL,
                       label_ids = NULL, include_spam_trash = NULL, page_token = NULL,
                       user_id = "xyz@abc.com"))
tbl1<- head(tbl2,1)

save_attachments(message(paste0(tbl1)), path="/Users/apple/Desktop", user_id="xyz@abc.com")
```

---

When I run this R script in Rstudio it runs successfully and the attachment is saved but when I try to run it in terminal it need manual authorization in browser to do the same task. In Rstudio it asked me to save the token as cache (Y?N) and after saving the token it never asks for the browser authentication.

Can you please help me out with this issue.

I am attaching the screenshot of terminal output for better understanding[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d32TP.png)

Comment: I edited your tags ... I suspect this is entirely an RStudio thing, but left most of the others for context in case I'm missing something.

Comment: why is there a bash tag here???

Comment: I was trying to create a bash file here to run it daily but as the script is posing an issue I can't opt for the bash file unless this issue is resolved

Comment: Do the oauth, and save your token as an object then save it as a file (generally `saveRDS`), in your script, read the token. You don't need to authenticate every time you send an email...

Comment: @JohnCoene can you help with how to do this in R. This work well in Android environment I am aware of that but I don't know how to do this in R.

Comment: It's detailed in the [README](https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/blob/master/README.md). Let me know if this doesn't work for you.